# SparkUI URL becomes inactive after spark standalone application mode finishes

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am very new to Spark and I am trying to run the SimpleApp.py in spark.
When I use spark-shell ./bin/pyspark , the url `http://192.168.0.11:4040/` remains intact till the time, the shell is active , but when I kill the shell and try to run spark standalone application

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn examples/SimpleApp.py
```

the url `http://192.168.0.11:4040/` is only active when the job is running. When it finishes I can't access the url.
How to keep the url always running in spark standalone mode.

I am using spark-1.1.1-bin-hadoop2.4 from spark official site and running the same in Mac-os

Comment: Wait, you want the process to stay alive forever so it can serve its UI? That sounds weird, but since it's your code, you can do it (just never exit the process and don't stop the Spark context). Or you can enable event logging and use the history server (check the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)).

Comment: Another vote in favor of event logging + history server; that's the best approach.

Comment: @vanza I didn't intent to make the job alive , but I wanted a url to access the finished job details or more precisely logs like hadoop and other give .. so ideally its the thing above mentioned ie event logging + history

Comment: @vanza Spot-on. Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer...

You can follow the [Monitoring docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) to enable event logging for your application, and you can then use Spark's History Server to render the UI of finished applications.