# Spark Standalone cluster master web UI inaccessible after an application finishes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark application that finishes without error, but once it's done and saved all of its outputs and the process terminates, the Spark standalone cluster master process becomes a CPU hog, using 16 CPU's full time for hours, and the web UI becomes unresponsive. I have no idea what it could be doing, is there some complicated clean up step?

Some more details:

I've got a Spark standalone cluster (27 workers/nodes) that I've been successfully submitting jobs to for a while. I recently scaled up the size of my applications, the largest now takes 3.5 hours using  100 cores over 27 workers, and each worker has ~dozens of GB of shuffle read/write over the course of the job. Otherwise, the application is no different than the smaller jobs that have run successfully before.

Comment: Note, this question has similar keywords but is substantially different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412780/sparkui-url-becomes-inactive-after-spark-standalone-application-mode-finishes. In that question, the asker wonders why his application's URL goes away when the app is over. In my question, I'm wondering why the master uses so much CPU after my job successfully completes

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Spark's standalone cluster, and is caused by the massive event log created by large applications. You can read more at the issue tracking link below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12299

At the current time, the best work-around is to disable event logging for large jobs.

Comment: After having read all the documentation I could, I turned to the Spark project's issue tracker and read every single critical issue report until I found this one. I'll leave the question up in case anyone else runs into this problem and is as stumped as I've been the past few days