# Spark 2.1.0 Web UI not showing "Application Detail UI"

Tags: apache-spark

I recently upgraded by Spark 1.4.1 setup to the latest 2.1.0. I'm running Spark in Standalone mode. Everything seems to work fine except the web UI. 
The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299264/spark-standalone-cluster-master-web-ui-inaccessible-after-an-application-finishe) here shows that this can happen for large application logs. But I'm pretty sure my application log is not large (~8.5MB).
I have copied the same setup that I was using in 1.4.1 with following parameters as

```
spark.eventLog.enabled             true
spark.eventLog.dir                 /LOCALPATH/spark/event-log
spark.history.fs.logDirectory      /LOCALPATH/spark/event-log
```

The web UI shows current and previous applications. However, the "Application Detail UI" link is only available for running/active applications and does not show for completed applications. I've checked the eventLog directory and it does have non-empty log file for completed applications.

Attached are images for reference as well. Am I missing some new property introduced in ver 2.1.0? I've gone through the documentation multiple times and couldn't find any.

[image: Finished application with no "Application Detail UI link"]

[image: Running application with "Application Detail UI" link]

EDIT: Got it working (for any future references)

I got it working through spark history server after following the steps explained [Spark History Server](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-history-server.html). In particular, I added a log4j property

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.deploy.history=INFO
```

in

```
SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties
```

and start the history server and access the history server interface through

```
<history-server-host>:18080
```

where *history-server-host* is usually the same as your master node.

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question mentioned by your post link but did you read the answer ?

Comment: The post suggests that this is due to "massive event log created by large applications". I have mentioned in the question that "application log is not large (~8.5MB)". The linked post in one of the comments refers to "enabling event logging" which I already have enabled. So Yes, I did read the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about a History server, It worked! We switched from Spark 1.6 to 2.2.0 and config that worked on our Standalone Spark cluster before stopped working, "Application Detail UI" disappeared.